# QR code scanner in Android app

Tags: java, android, qr-code

I want to scan QR-code in my app. I don't want to use ZXing, since it refers to Google Play if the user doesn't have this application installed on the device. I also found this: https://github.com/Gnzlt/AndroidVisionQRReader , but I cannot install it to the Android Studio, all 3 method proposed by the author faild. 
Maybe you know something else (maybe to just put a dependency into the gradle)?

Comment: Why is it failing? Maybe you did something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. Here it is: https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner
I used ZXing, but it doesn't require an additional app on the device.

Comment: you never said that you do not know how to handle the android camera. you wanted to use zxing without downloading the zxing app, that is what my code snippet does.

Answer (score 1):

Since this Library uses Android Vision , Why don't you try to implement you own code using the android-vision project as a sample , it will you a lot more control and flexibility also the sample is fairly easy to understand and directly from google.

You can find the Overview [here](https://developers.google.com/vision/barcodes-overview)

and the sample project on github [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision)

I tried Running the Barcodereader sample and it works perfectly(for QR as well as barcodes) , MainActivity and the BarcodeCaptureActivity is mainly what you'll need edit for your custom implementation.

Answer (score -1):

just add

```
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
```

to the dependencies section of your app build.gradle file and you can use the zxing java interface, no need to install the zxing app:

```
MultiFormatReader mReader = new MultiFormatReader();
Map<DecodeHintType,Object> hints = new EnumMap<DecodeHintType,Object>(DecodeHintType.class);
hints.put(DecodeHintType.TRY_HARDER, true);
// select your barcode formats here
List<BarcodeFormat> formats = Arrays.asList(BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE);
hints.put(DecodeHintType.POSSIBLE_FORMATS, formats);

mReader.setHints(hints);

// your camera image here
Bitmap input;
int width = input.getWidth(), height = input.getHeight();
int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
input.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
input.recycle();
input = null;
BinaryBitmap bb = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(new RGBLuminanceSource(width, height, pixels)));
Result result = mReader.decodeWithState(bb);
String resultString = result.getText();
```

Comment: Bitmap input I need to initialize. What do I have to put there?

Comment: @ninja_2012 the camera image....